# YAML, cmd based shell, if else conditions is not working

Tags: github, cmd, yaml

I am writing CICD in the YAML file of GitHub, therein one instance I need to compare the branch names where a pull request is being triggered to determine which environment the other underlying process thereafter should use to the do `MsBuild` and other tasks.

Below is the comparison in YAML:

```
 - name: build
   shell: cmd
   run: |
        
        if not x%GITHUB_REF_NAME:RSDEV_=%==x%GITHUB_REF_NAME% (
            SET PLATFORM=Qa
           ) else if not x%GITHUB_REF_NAME:Feature_=%==x%GITHUB_REF_NAME% (
            SET PLATFORM=Qa
          ) else if not x%GITHUB_REF_NAME:Release_=%==x%GITHUB_REF_NAME%(
            SET PLATFORM=Uat
          ) else (
            echo "Check something went wrong"
            exit 1
          )
```

However, when I ran `pull-request`, it says

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

Am I following the correct way for branch comparison like `release_**` and so on `cmd`?

Comment: You need a space before the opening parenthesis on line `9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw, I was able to figure out the reason behind the error: `The syntax of the command is incorrect`

There was an indentation error in the else block:

```
- name: build
   shell: cmd
   run: |
        
        if not x%GITHUB_REF_NAME:RSDEV_=%==x%GITHUB_REF_NAME% (
            SET PLATFORM=Qa
        ) else if not x%GITHUB_REF_NAME:Feature_=%==x%GITHUB_REF_NAME% (
            SET PLATFORM=Qa
        ) else if not x%GITHUB_REF_NAME:Release_=%==x%GITHUB_REF_NAME%(
            SET PLATFORM=Uat
        ) else (
            echo "Check something went wrong"
            exit 1
        )
```

[Courtesy Edit]

The correct syntax in cmd.exe:

```bash
        if /i not "%GITHUB_REF_NAME:RSDEV_=%" == "%GITHUB_REF_NAME%" (
            SET "PLATFORM=Qa"
        ) else if /i not "%GITHUB_REF_NAME:Feature_=%" == "%GITHUB_REF_NAME%" (
            SET "PLATFORM=Qa"
        ) else if /i not "%GITHUB_REF_NAME:Release_=%" == "%GITHUB_REF_NAME%" (
            SET "PLATFORM=Uat"
        ) else (
            echo Check something went wrong
            exit 1
        )
```

Comment: You still have a missing space before the opening parenthesis, as did your initial submission. As a courtesy I have included the correct syntax for use in `cmd.exe`